# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError for valid JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that's valid according to [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/), but Python's `json.load` function can't handle it. Why? How do I fix this?

The file (`file.json`):

```json
{
    "bookmarks": {
        "accounts": {
            "lastupdated": "2022-06-28T16:12:15.581000Z"
        }
    },
    "currently_syncing": null
}
```

I try this:

```py
import json

with open("file.json") as f:
    json.load(f)
```

Throws:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "~\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "~\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "~\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "~\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

(Tildes `~` added in place of paths to my home directory.)

I tried Python 3.7.9 and 3.9.10, both installed via [`pyenv-win`](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win) on Windows 10.

Comment: It could be that you used some Windows tool to create the file that adds a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file that is confusing the Python parser. I cannot reproduce the issue on linux.

Comment: try to `ret = f.read();print(ret);json.loads(ret)` so that to see the file is actually loaded fine

Comment: @DmitriChubarov and @EvgenyKolyakov, you're right. `with open("file.json") as f: ret = f.read();print(ret)` returns `ÿþ{"bookmarks": {"accounts": {"lastupdated": "2022-06-28T17:13:37.667000Z"}}, "currently_syncing": null}`. Any idea what's creating those weird `ÿþ` characters? `file.json` is output from a Python package. What should I look for in that package that would create those characters on Windows?

Comment: I guess a bad copy paste from some Google service of some Widows editor... The like adding invisible symbols... How was it created ?